# Baby lifting: 16kg × 2 dumbbell routine suggestion?

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, strength-training, workout-types

Baby seat is 16kg, baby is 10kg (assume will be 16 soon enough!).

My gym is inaccessible until March, so going to buy a couple of 12kg dumbbells and:

- curls
- reverse curls
- Zottman curls
- rows
- bench press
- deadlift
- squats
- lunges

Starting with 3 sets of 6 reps with expectation of 12 reps by March. 5 days a week.

Pushups (20 to start) and pull-ups (8 to start) also.

What do you think? - Will this suffice? - Any exercises to add/remove? - And is it ok to do same routine everyday?

PS: I've only just fixed all my back issues; trick was the rowing machine in the gym. So want to take care not to injure…

Comment: Overhead pressing , zercher squats are most important for these matters

Comment: @trystwithfreedom I don’t think they can do zercher squats at all, since they don’t have a barbell, and more importantly, unless you just like doing zercher squats, there are several other movements that are superior for whatever strength and hypertrophy goals one might have. Zerchers are an inferior exercise for numerous reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row, bench press, deadlifts, squats, lunges; these are all good excercise but the 3 different curls are unnecessary, you don't need 3 different exercises for a fairly small muscle. Although dumbell bench press is an excellent chest exercise, if all you have are 12kg dumbells, it might not be sufficient. 12kg will likely not be enough to properly stimulate the chest muscles. Even if 12kg is your current 6 rep max, your strength will very quickly outgrow those weights. When doing home workouts I would focus on the push-ups and incline push up for your chest and maybe moving onto harder variations when your strength increases. Same goes for your back, 12kg dumbell rows won't be enough, focus more on pullups and maybe Australian pull ups for mid back and traps. The 12kg's will probably be suitable for curls, shoulder press and maybe also chest flys. I'm not sure about doing deadlifts at home without a barbell but lunges can be done with fairly small dumbells and an easy way to get some decent resistance for at home squats is to get some resistance bands. Place one end of the band under both feet and the other around the back of your neck/over your shoulders.

Comment: Ok cool. Yeah I haven't done any arm workouts in many years. The main thing is carrying these big items around for long periods of times. - Open to a completely different routine. - Will have access to a full gym from around March; so want to build stabiliser and initial muscles so I can start lifting serious in the gym then. - Can add chest flys and those other pullups + pushups. - Maybe I'll buy those resistance bands also. - Anything else? - 

Comment: Slightly contrary to what I've previously said, but the Initial increase in perceived strength for a beginner is actually muscle memory and learning the movement. So, although low resistance wouldn't cause much hypertrophy, it can still be useful in helping you learn/re-learn the movement and perfect your form.

Comment: Romanian deadlifts could be done with dumbbells. 12kg could also be used for weighted pull-ups.